# How to work with maps in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, maps, blackberry-maps

Based on the BlackBerry knowledge center article, [How To - Invoke BlackBerry Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKlhF.png), I tried to use maps in BlackBerry.

However, it is not efficient and throws unknown exception.

so i need another way to deal with maps in blackberry.

---

the exception only happen on simulator .
i tested it on real device the exception doesn't happen.

but i can't see the map

like this [image]

so what is the problem ?

Comment: Do you want to embed map in your app or simply launch maps application?

Comment: i want to display map with mutltiple anotation. i don't know what it is the difference between them

Comment: This is because you need to have a sim card with BIS service from your operator. If you don't have that, you can only use google maps which works much better anyway.